# Android SQL no such table?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm very new to droid development but I was working on some SQL. I have an class which extends the SQLOpenDatabaseHelper and in the onCreate() method I execute this :

```
        public static final String CREATE_DB = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_VOCAB_INFO
        + "(" + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_URL
        + " TEXT NOT NULL," + COLUMN_DOWNLOADED + "TEXT NOT NULL);";
```

However, when I try to add something to the database like so :

```
        //Adding method 
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_NAME, "item " + i);
        cv.put(COLUMN_URL, "random url");
        cv.put(COLUMN_DOWNLOADED, "true");
        open();
        database.insert(TABLE_VOCAB_INFO, null, cv);
```

I get the error:

```
      (1) no such table: vocab_info
```

How would I resolve this?

EDIT: more info.

I am creating the database in the onCreate() method of the helper like this:

```
      public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_DB);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            System.out.println("Error with creation");
        }
    }
```

I access the database using the adding method like this

```
          public void onClick(View viewSelected) {
    switch (viewSelected.getId()) {
    case R.id.bDownload:
        DatabaseManipulator dm = new DatabaseManipulator(this);
        dm.open();
        dm.addList(null);
        dm.addList(null);
        dm.addList(null);
        dm.addList(null);
        dm.addList(null);
        for (VocabList list : dm.getAllLists()) {
            System.out.println(list.getName());
        }
        dm.close();
        break;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show more code? For example how are you reading data from database (because I assume, that this error appears during reading data)?

Comment: you will also need to put space between Column name and v type here `COLUMN_DOWNLOADED + "TEXT NOT NULL);";`

Comment: No, the error appears during the code I put in.

Comment: But why would it not be? Surely an SQLException would be thrown and this is in a try-catch block?

Comment: Then show us where are you creating your Database using your `CREATE_DB` String, and when this putting data part is being executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) try below create table statement.

```
 public static final String CREATE_DB = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_VOCAB_INFO
        + "(" + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_URL
        + " TEXT NOT NULL," + COLUMN_DOWNLOADED + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
```

2) If you making any changes to `table structure` or adding new table, You ll need to uninstall and `re-install` your application , as `onCreate` use to call once if there is no DB created, If DB is already there onCreate wont be called and your changes will not gonna affect DB.

Worked for OP >> **you can also do this by changing DB version.**

Comment: Hmm - changing the database version from 1 to 2 seemed to work. Thanks!